# Remove an array if exists inside an array in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5cca927ed5494b0"),
"userName": "1234",
"rcReviews": [{
        "userName": "qwert",
        "finalReview": "qtrwyw",
        "dField": [{
                "name": "t2",
                "status": "Not Verified",
                "reviewComment": "asdfag"
            },
            {
                "status": "Not Verified",
                "reviewComment": "asegqrt",
                "name": "t13"
            },
            {
                "name": "c452",
                "status": "Not Verified",
                "reviewComment": "gaeqrtqa "
            },
            {
                "status": "Not Verified",
                "reviewComment": "tyqiqooqa",
                "name": "c13"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "userName": "1517",
        "finalReview": "wsywx",
        "dField": [{
                "status": "Not Verified",
                "reviewComment": "aswrrwgqrt",
                "name": "t113"
            },
            {
                "name": "c1516",
                "status": "Not Verified",
                "reviewComment": "gaeqredectqa "
            },
        ]
    }
]}
```

I want a query which checks dField array key exists in rcReveiws array. If it exists then it has remove the dField array and other contents should be there only dField array should be removed

Comment: Hi! What have you tried?

Comment: db.newcopy.updateMany({
    "rcReviews": {
        "$elemMatch": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "dField": {
                    "$exists": true
                }
            }
        }
    }
}, {
    "$unset": {
        "rcReviews.$[].$[].dField": ""
    }}
    )                              I had tried like this. Thank you for responding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the below query. It has been tested with the data provided by you

```
db.testmongo.update({"rcReviews.dField":{$exists:true}},{$unset:{"rcReviews.$[].dField":""}},{multi:true})
```

Change the collection name to match yours. 
The query checks for records that contain the `dField` attribute in `rcReviews` array. It updates all the objects inside that array and removes the `dField` attribute using unset

Comment: Thank you Abhishek Kothari. I have another doubt,  if i wanted to remove another key inside the array and that key is type object so if i change name that's enough right no need to change whole query??